# I want to split a Slate editor input into parts by click split&add button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, slate

I have Slate editor input and `Split&Add` button on react typescript.
I want the input to be split into two separate inputs from the point cursor stands. For example, if I have
*"I want to split this text into two parts. Here is the first part (assume here the cursor). And here the second part."* Whenever I click `Split&Add` button, There should be three separate slate editor inputs:

1. Input with "I want to split this text into two parts. Here is the first part" value
2. Empty input with cursor
3. Input with "And here the second part." value.

I was assuming I can do it by selecting cursor place, and getting/setting its value to a new variable (so that I will set it to the third new input). And deleting the value after cursor point.

My code, now, looks something like this

```
 const [isSplit, setIsSplit] = useState(false);

// function for the button
const onSplitEditor = (): void => {
    setIsSplit(true);
    const { selection } = editor;

    if (selection) {
      // Get the point after the cursor
      const pointAfterCursor = Editor.after(editor, selection.focus);

      // Set the value after the cursor to a variable
      if (pointAfterCursor !== undefined) {
        const valueAfterCursor = Editor.string(editor, {
          anchor: {
            path: pointAfterCursor.path,
            offset: pointAfterCursor.offset - 1,
          },
          focus: Editor.end(editor, []),
        });

        if (valueAfterCursor) {
          // Delete the content after the cursor
          Transforms.delete(editor, {
            at: selection,
            distance: 1,
            unit: 'line',
          });
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-debugger
        // debugger;
        console.log('valueAfterCursor =>', valueAfterCursor);
      }
    }
  };

  // split and add editor input once add button is clicked
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isSplit) {
      setIsSplit(false);
    }
  }, []);

return (
<>
 <Slate
        editor={editor}
        initialValue={value}
        onChange={(value: Descendant[]): void => setValue(value)}
      >
        <Editable
          placeholder="Optional text"
          renderElement={renderElement}
          className="editor__input"
          onKeyDown={(e): void => onKeyDown(e, editor)}
          onFocus={(): void => setIsFocused(true)}
          onBlur={(): void => setIsFocused(false)}
        />
      </Slate>

{isSplit && (

<Slate
        editor={editor}
        initialValue={valueAfterCursor}
        onChange={(value: Descendant[]): void => setValue(value)}
      >
        <Editable
          placeholder="Optional text"
          renderElement={renderElement}
          className="editor__input"
          onKeyDown={(e): void => onKeyDown(e, editor)}
          onFocus={(): void => setIsFocused(true)}
          onBlur={(): void => setIsFocused(false)}
        />
      </Slate>
)}
</>
)
```